# LFTP mkdir -p doesn't work with sftp protocol?

Tags: ftp, mkdir

here is the server directory structure:

/tmp/a

and I can only connect to the server with sftp

Now I want to mkdir first, and then upload some files into it.

mkdir -p /tmp/a/b works, but mkdir -p /tmp/a/b/c/d/e/f/g doesn't.

I think the param -p is for this situation, anything wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

New version lftp support `mkdir -p` with sftp protocal.

Comment: Hi Can you please post a syntax of how to use mkdir with sfpt? Please

Answer (score 0):

```
mput -d some/path/file.txt
```

Create directories the same as in file names  and  put the files into them.