# LFTP - Create directory if it does not exist

Tags: linux, bash, lftp

I would like to use LFTP to create a directory if it does not exist. It should be a "one-liner":

This does already work:

`lftp -c "open -u user,pass server; mkdir /test`

The

`lftp -c "open -u user,pass server; mkdir -p /test`

fails if the directory already exists:

> mkdir: Zugriff nicht möglich:550-Can't create directory: File exists 16 files used (0%) - authorized: 50000 files 1286621 Kbytes used (0%) - authorized: 512000000 Kb (/test2)

But it does fail if the directory does already exist. How can I do this more elegant?

Comment: did you try googling this? I get a number of results, including: [this](https://github.com/welaika/wordmove/issues/103) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171236/lftp-mkdir-p-doesnt-work-with-sftp-protocol).

In other words, are you using the latest version of `lftp`?

Comment: Yes, I tried to. LFTP is `LFTP | Version 4.0.9 | Copyright (c) 1996-2010 Alexander V. Lukyanov` which is installed from the repo.

Comment: yeah I can't seem to find an answer there either. But there [is](https://lftp.yar.ru/news.html) a newer version of LFTP, you could try to upgrade and see if that helps.

Comment: still wouldn't get my hopes up, from the same page as in my comment above: Version 3.7.12 - 2009-04-28

    fixed core dump on `mput -d' command.
    fixed a core dump on `kill' command.
    fixed mkdir -p for sftp protocol.
    fixed some signed/unsigned conversion bugs.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `mkdir -f` option to suppress the error message. The option is available starting with 4.5.2 version. The latest lftp version is 4.7.3.

Comment: tried `-f` on lftp `v4.7.4`, it fails silently. We are using lftp for auto-deploy (not my decision), and have more commands after it, but deployer does not proceed to the next command even with `-f`.

Comment: "mkdir -f /path || .true" can help

Comment: `-f` suppresses the error message, but still causes lftp to return non-zero exit code

Answer (score 4):

If you can't upgrade to the latest version of lftp, you can use this :

```
lftp -c "cd /my/new/directory || mkdir -p /my/new/directory"
```

It will create the directory only if it can't enter it.

Comment: `cd /my/new/directory` will also throw an error if the directory does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like
`mkdir -pf  /my/new/directory || cd /my/new/directory`
is a solution for me: no error messages, no error codes, unless there is something wrong with the directory (permissions, the name exists as a file etc.)

UPD: In my case I only needed to create directory. If the command used in a longer script, additional `cd` command might be needed, since the working directory after the command above depends on whether `/my/new/directory` existed before.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean simply `mkdir -p /test`?

Answered here: [How to mkdir only if a dir does not already exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793858/how-to-mkdir-only-if-a-dir-does-not-already-exist)

From the `mkdir --help`:

> -p, --parents     no error if existing, make parent directories as needed

Comment: I added this to my initial question. The -p does not work.

Comment: lftp's mkdir does not equal to the linux shell's mkdir